# .htaccess Rewrite url with images from a folder to a php file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all the images in my wp-content/uploads folder to a thumbs.php file in wp-content/thumb folder without changing url

This is what I have added in my .htacccess

```
# BEGIN img
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !someweirdcrawler
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.+?)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ /wp-content/thumbs/index.php?img_source=http://mywebsite.com/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
# END img
# other wordpress default stuff including wp-fastest-cache
```

This is what I want to achieve 
Visitors visit my site or any image with urls like

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2050/12/Hello-Dolly-1.0.0.1-words.jpg
```

and the rewrites should be

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/thumbs/index.php?img_source=http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2050/12/Hello-Dolly-1.0.0.1-words.jpg
```

*For those who may think... thumbs.php is not timthumb file. I have written my own script for lossless image compression

**UPDATE:**
Its working for my other site.. What could be the problem?

**FINAL UPDATE:**
For Those Who come to find answers Later.
So Finally It was because of my WP FASTEST CACHE htaccess Code. Just removed the -d Directive and worked like a charm. But I am not using this code anymore because I have found better Options.

Here's the code:

```
# BEGIN img
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#show original images to Image crawler Like wordpress photon or google images.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !someweirdcrawler
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.+?)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ /wp-content/thumbs/index.php?img_source=http://mywebsite.com/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
# END img
# other wordpress default stuff including wp-fastest-cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

The requested image is never going to be both a file **and** a directory, so your condition is never going to match and the request is never going to be rewritten. A valid request for an image should only be a file, so remove the second `RewriteCond` directive (`-d` directory check).

> Its working for my other site..

Are you sure (the code is the same)?

Comment: Yes I have tested it on one of my site. And even after removing second RewriteCond directive (directory check) Its not working. What could be the problem. Is my rewriterule correct?

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` looks OK, providing the paths are correct? So, what happens exactly? Nothing? Any errors? Is mod_rewrite enabled? Are per-directory .htaccess files permitted? Is mod_rewrite allowed in .htaccess on this server? (To be honest, I don't see how it could work on your other site if you have the `-d` condition? Is your other site Apache/Linux?) Are both server configs the same?

Comment: It goes to the original and shows the original image. and I think mod_rewrite must be already enabled because wordpredd need mod_rewrite. Eve Though how to che3ck if it is disabled?

Comment: So, it seems that _nothing_ is happening - the `RewriteRule` is not doing anything. You could just try making it a temporary redirect (add the `R` flag) - just to be sure that nothing is happening. Is it possible that other directives that follow are rewriting this request again? (If WordPress is functioning OK, with "pretty" URLs then mod_rewrite must be working.)

Comment: No even after adding Adding [R] Flag its not working.

Comment: Try taking out _all_ the preceding `RewriteCond` directives, leaving just the `RewriteRule`.