# How to remove directory path form image url using htaccess?

Tags: image, .htaccess, magento

```
http://example.com/abc/media 
TO
http://example.com/media
```

How to set this URL with use of .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If u using only for image. You can try with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^.*/abc/media/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/media/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:code]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]/

This is my htaccess file. @NguyenVQ

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:aaa]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]/
This is my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:aaa]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]/
```

This is my .htaccess file.

Now we need to remove `/abc/` folder from image URL so we get all image URL from the Root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^.*/abc/media/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/media/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Already Try this but not working on my site.

Comment: Could you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899397/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-images-from-a-folder-to-a-php-file hope it help your issue

Comment: Thanks but not help that.